# Iterating over a dataTable causes an issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
@using System.Data
@Model  IEnumerable<ReportingTotalsViewModel>
...
                        <tbody>
                            @{
                                var dataTable = Model[0].Value;
                                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@row["Month"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["# Issued"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["# Closed"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["% Closed"]</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

From my controller, I am passing

```
var viewAndDataTable = new List<KeyValuePair<String, DataTable>>();
...
return View(viewAndDataTable);
```

At runtime, I get this error.

> RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `.Rows` on you dataTable.

Try:

```
@using System.Data
@Model  IEnumerable<ReportingTotalsViewModel>
...
                        <tbody>
                            @{
                                var dataTable = Model[0].Value;
                                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>@row["Month"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["# Issued"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["# Closed"]</td>
                                        <td>@row["% Closed"]</td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            }
                        </tbody>
```

Comment: do I have to use the column name? can I use the index?

Comment: Since it is a `KeyValuePair`, it is normally best to use the `Key` name as index.